# Status and selectivity of open access journals

Tags: publications

I am wondering about the following (after reading this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7980/why-do-many-recent-open-access-mega-journals-only-cover-biological-sciences) that discusses open access journals):

1. Is it easier to publish in one of the open access journals (when compared to the traditional journals)?
2. Does publishing in one of the open access journals affect the academic value of an article? (Unsure how to put this, but I mean does it affect your reputation etc?)

I note that some of the open access journals are peer-reviewed.

An example of open access is the [Directory of Open Access Journals](http://www.doaj.org/doaj?func=home&uiLanguage=en).

Comment: We recently had a related discussion here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/value-of-light-to-none-peer-reviewed-pay-to-publish-articles

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open access vs. closed access is a totally separate issue from quality of journal.  There are high quality open access journals and low quality ones, and high quality traditional journals and low quality ones.  There may be some correlation because open access journals tend to be newer and so less established, but nonetheless if you want to determine the quality of a particular journal you should look at that specific journal not try to extrapolate based on whether it's open access or not.